# Stuck at a basic ethers.js/hardhat problem | Console logging my array results in undefined

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

Hello guys I was playing around with hardhat/ethers.js using Typescript but got stuck on.

Here are my ***imports:***

```
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers"
import { ethers } from "hardhat"
import { beforeEach, describe, it } from "mocha"
```

my fullscope **variables:**

```
let signersWithAddress: SignerWithAddress[]
let addresses: string[]
```

And here is my **basic mocha test:**

```
describe("Basic Test", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        signersWithAddress = await ethers.getSigners()
        signersWithAddress.map(async (_signer: SignerWithAddress) =>
            addresses.push(await _signer.getAddress())
        )
    })
    it("Prints every address that we have", () => {
        console.log(addresses)
    })
})
```

When I run yarn hardhat test on my terminal, I get this output(**undefined** comes from console.log):

```bash
 Basic Test
undefined
    ✔ Prints every address that we have


  1 passing (719ms)

Done in 2.85s.
```

Where is the mistake and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let addresses: string[]` doesn't initialize `addresses` to anything, so unless something assigns an array to the variable, it will just be `undefined`. `addresses.push(await _signer.getAddress())` doesn't assign a new array to the variable if it is `undefined`. you need to do that manually. Just try doing the following in the your browser console:

```js
let a
a.push(1) // will error since a is undefined
```

Instead, you should do:

```js
let signersWithAddress: SignerWithAddress[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for guidance. Here is the final working version of the code:

```
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers"
import { ethers } from "hardhat"
import { beforeEach, describe, it } from "mocha"

let signersWithAddress: SignerWithAddress[] = []
let addresses: string[] = []

describe("Basic Test", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const signersArray = await ethers.getSigners()
        await Promise.all(
            signersArray.map(async (i) => {
                addresses.push(await i.getAddress())
            })
        )
    })
    it("Prints every address that we have", () => {
        console.log(addresses)
    })
})
```